# Agregar codificación utf-8 al descargar un xls con javascript desde mysql

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

Estoy descargando un archivo con mis de las tablas traídas de **mysql** pero al momento de abrir mi archivo xls no tiene la codificación utf-8 y hay caracteres ilegibles.

Este es el código **JavaScript** que estoy utilizando para descargar ese archivo **xls**

```html
 <script>
   function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel/charset=utf-8';
    var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    
    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';
    
    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;
    
        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
  }
 </script>
```

y este es mi botón con el que ejecuto la función de Javascript

```html
<button onclick="exportTableToExcel('order_table-col', 'members-data')">Export Table Data To Excel File</button>
```

Comment: Lo que debes mostrarnos es **up_calendar.php**

Comment: @Fly Perdón estaba mostrando código incorrecto en el primer Script

Comment: A ver, creo que quizá sea al revés, debes usar codificación `ISO-8859-1` para que excel lo lea correctamente. Si es así acuérdate de usar `utf8_decode()` en los datos, que seguramente vengan en `utf-8` de mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que lo que tienes mal es la codificación de caracteres, que debes asignarla al crear el contenido mediante `header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=ISO-8859-1')`;

Te dejo aquí la función que uso yo para exportar a csv:

```
/**
 *  Exporta los valores de $valores a un fichero .csv delimitado por punto y coma, usando comillas como delimitador de cadenas
 * 
 * @param array $valores
 * @param string $nombre
 * @param array $opciones
 */
function exportar_csv($valores, $nombre, $opciones = array()) {
    ob_clean();

    if (strstr($nombre, '.csv') === false) {
        $nombre = $nombre . '.csv';
    }

    $cabecera = '';
    foreach (current($valores) as $index => $value) {
        $cabecera .= '"' . utf8_decode($index) . '"' . ';';
    }

    $csv = '';
    $csv .= $cabecera . chr(10) . chr(13);
    foreach ($valores as $index => $row) {
        foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
            $csv .= '"' . utf8_decode($v) . '"' . ';';
        }
        $csv .= chr(10) . chr(13);
    }

    $test = (isset($opciones['test']) AND ( $opciones['test'] == true));

    if ($test) {
        header('Content-Type: text; charset=ISO-8859-1');
    } else {
        header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=ISO-8859-1');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $nombre);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($csv));
    }
    echo $csv;
    die(0);
}
```

> **TIP**
>
> Se podría mejorar aceptando como parámetro también el tipo de
>   codificación de cracteres.

Comment: je, je... tras la modificación del código ni me di cuenta, te aporto una respuesta `php` y tu necesitas una `javascript`.  De todas formas la dejo, por ahora, pues si el problema es de codificación de caracteres algo te puede ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Te faltó agregar el código de tu función exportTableToExcel.
Suponiendo que ocupas esta función que encontré:

```
function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';

    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['ufeff', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;

        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
}
```

Tendrías que modificar la función agregando la codificación del archivo en la cabecera dataType de la siguiente manera:

```
var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel' +  ';charset=utf-8';
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, he probado añadiendo esta linea de código por la que tenía pero aún me sigue descargando el archivo con caracteres ilegibles y al abrirlo me muestra este mensaje http://prntscr.com/ncucbo